# Unable To Resolve issue Getting in Next 12 AMP

Tags: reactjs, next.js, compiler-errors, amp-html

```
<amp-list
  height="277"
  layout="fixed-height"
  src="${relatedArticlesUrl}"
  items="." 
  single-item="."
>
 <div placeholder>Loading ...</div>
 <div fallback>Failed to load data.</div>
 <template type="amp-mustache">
 <div class="slction_section">
  <amp-carousel height="254" layout="fixed-height" type="carousel" role="region" aria-label="Basic usage   carousel" data-next-button-aria-label="Go to next slide" data-previous-button-aria-label="Go to previous slide">
    {{#items}}
    <a class="districtSelect" href={{url}} data-vars-event-label='{{title}},{{id}}' data-vars-event-category="Related_Story">
     <figure><amp-img src={{thumbnail}}?im=Resize,width=201,aspect=fit,type=normal height="134" width="201" /></figure>
      <p>{{title}}</p>
    </a>
    {{/items}}
   </amp-carousel>
  </div>
 </template>
</amp-list>
```

/amp/article  error  The extension 'amp-list' is referenced at version 'undefined' which is an invalid version. Please use a valid version of this extension.  https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-list

error  The extension 'amp-list' is referenced at version 'undefined' which is an invalid version. Please use a valid version of this extension.  https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-list

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YmMg.png
```

Comment: Can you share `<script>` tag of amp-list?